# Force mysql to record NULL if field was left empty?

Tags: mysql, null

Here is the situation:

I have a optional input fields, which I don't care if user fills in or not. If he leave is it empty, I want NULL recorded.

And then there is this field for example: DECIMAL (10,2), marked that it can be NULL and default value is set to NULL.

And for example I have input field like this that corresponds to it:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" size="4"/>
```

If I submit form without touching this field MySQL records it as 0.00. Is there any way to force it to record NULL instead?

PS. Same goes for other field types. For example i have INT as well. In that case `0` gets recorded.

PPS. If I go to insert the given record through PhpMyAdmin, and leave the given fields empty, then NULL values gets recorded as desired.

**HTML**

```
<label>Svoris: <input type="text" name="load_weight1" size="4"></label>
<label>Tūris(m<sup>3</sup>)<input type="text" name="load_volume1" size="4"></label>
```

**PHP**

```
$data["load_weight"] = $this->input->post("load_weight1");
$data["load_volume"] = $this->input->post("load_volume1");
$quoteid = $this->uzklausos_forma_model->saveRecord($data);
```

**saveRecord()**

```
function saveRecord($items)
{
    $this->db->insert('request_quote', $items);
    return $this->db->insert_id();  
}
```

Comment: Set it as NULL in the relevant database insert. (Without seeing how you're handling the form data capture, etc. it's impossible to answer your question.) At the very least, you need to tag your question with the relevant scripting language you're using and provide the code you use to parse the form data receipt and insert it into the database.

Comment: it is a huge piece of code, since it is a complex form. I will try and excerpt all the relevant code for one field, and will update my question. Oh and I am using codeigniter

Comment: Cause `$_REQUEST["foo"]` will be an empty string, not a `NULL`. So this empty string is convert to 0.00 or 0 when you populate your table. So without seeing your code around the form and to populate your DB, we can't help.

Comment: Added all the code for one field. Ill give another look, but it doesnt look like anything else messes with these post values :)

Comment: You need to look at the class to see what's happen in `$this->db->insert('request_quote', $items);`

Comment: If you can provide the code inside the `insert` function, it will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle that with a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_tbl_null BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.value = "" THEN
        SET NEW.value = NULL;
    END IF;
END;
```

The above code will tell to MySQL to replace before each `INSERT` statement the content of the column *value* by NULL if it is empty.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b259/1 for a live example

Comment: that wont work. Id be happy enough even if instead null it would leave an empty string. But instead it gives stuff like 0,00 or 0 or whatever other formatting is set :)

Comment: This will work only for `CHAR` (or `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`) columns. For numeric columns, the conversion is done using the host language rules  *before* the request is send to the server. If you don't have to perform calculation (including sort) on your numeric values at DB level you might change the column type to `CHAR` or equivalent. I would think about that mostly as a "hack" thought...

Comment: More "hackish" if the `0.00` value is not possible in your column, you could adapt the trigger to replace `0.00` by NULL. Well, very hackish indeed. Don't do that!

Comment: no I actually don't need to calculations on it. I only ever need to spit it out to the user, and possibly update it. Well yeah it is a hacky thing to do, but in this case it might just do the trick :) I will try that now.

PS. Would I be able to use nummber_format() on it (just to get 2 decimal places) and still store it as char?

Comment: @galdikas As a matter of fact, MySQL silently convert string to numbers when needed. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17951 for various examples. So my previous concern about calculation is mostly not founded. You won't be able to sort *numerically* however.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add some conditions in the PHP part. So if the value is empty, the field will not be pass to the `saveRecord` function...

```
if ($this->input->post("load_weight1")!="") {
    $data["load_weight"] = $this->input->post("load_weight1");
}
if ($this->input->post("load_volume1")!="") {
    $data["load_volume"] = $this->input->post("load_volume1");
}
$quoteid = $this->uzklausos_forma_model->saveRecord($data);
```